# use system script advertising in wordpress multisite

Tags: php, functions, multisite, blog-id

I have a little problem that I can not solve. I have a website "multi-site" system with ADS script. I wish I could enter leaderboard banner.

This is an example script:

```
<div id=""><script src=""></script><script src="" ></script></div>
```

i have insert this code script is work, but the problem is that it appears the entire network, instead I wish that each script is separate and in each subdomain change advertising by area.

it correct this recall:

```
<?php

if ( get_current_blog_id() === 1 ) {
```

how can I integrate the php code with the script?

Answer (score 0):

I have write :

```
<?php
    $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
?>
<?php if( 1 == $blog_id ); ?>
    <div id=""><script src=""></script><script src="" ></script></div>
<?php elseif( 2 == $blog_id ): ?>
    <div id=""><script src=""></script><script src="" ></script></div>
<?php else: ?>
    Default script
<?php endif; ?>
```

It correct !?

Answer (score 0):

OK perfect.
There was a syntax error in this line:

```
<?php if( 1 == $blog_id ); ?>
```

replaced:

```
<?php if( 1 == $blog_id ): ?>
```

close post.